# Elasticsearch 5.x setQuery deprecated

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-5

I have a question regarding the last version of Elasticsearch.

Until the previous version I was using the following Java API search:

```
SearchRequestBuilder request = client.prepareSearch(index).setSource(jsonQuery)
```

Now `setSource` is deprecated and it is recommended to use `setQuery(QueryBuilder)` instead.

Is it possible to pass the whole json query as before?

This is the query syntax I was using and I would like to keep if it is possible:

```
"{"
+ "\"query\": {"
+ "    \"bool\": {"
+ "      \"filter\": { ... }"
+ "     }"
+ "  },"
+ "  \"fields\": ["
+ "    \"xxx\","
+ "  ],"
+ "  \"size\": 1000"
+ "}";
```

I do not want to split body, fields and size using:

```
setQuery(QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(jsonQuery)).setSize(size).storedFields(fields)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery()`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/QueryBuilders.java#L605-L607) which will create an instance of [`WrapperQueryBuilder`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/WrapperQueryBuilder.java) in order to achieve this:

```
SearchRequestBuilder request = client.prepareSearch(index)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(jsonQuery))
    .setSize(1000)
    .fields("xxx1", "xxx2");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Val. I have already tried this implementation but in this way I am not able to include the stored fields from jsonQuery since I am defining the body.

Comment: Not sure I understand, can you elaborate? Update your question with the query you were doing previously and what won't work with this solution.

Comment: Please update your question and format your code, it'll be more legible and easier to help you.

Comment: Indeed, you'll need to specify the `fields` and `size` differently, directly on the request object.

Comment: I hoped there was still a way to declare all the query from a String. Anyway thank you for your help